# No naming ng-app directive

Tags: angularjs

This is a very simple template in Angular:

```
<div id="main" ng-app ng-controller="mycontrol">
  Quantity: <input type="number"  ng-model="qty">
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

and app.js file

```
var x=angular.module('ng');
x.controller('mycontrol',function($scope){
    $scope.qty=192;
});
```

I am trying to get the angular.module *without giving a name* to the application. **Is that possible?** I've read somewhere, we can use `ng`, however the above code does not work...

Comment: Why would you not want to name the application?

Comment: If you use angular-route, you dont need to specify ng-app because it is resolved with the routes. In basic angular, you have to.

Comment: This works fine? http://plnkr.co/edit/WM9Ig1CjZMvDNalZaiCt?p=preview

Comment: It works by just applying `src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"`. Why that?